# Query Whether or Not Two Integers in Array have Difference of D

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Here's the problem I'm having trouble with: you're given a list of $n$ integers, $a_i$, $a_2$, ... $a_n$, in the range $1$ to $10^9$. You need to find out whether or not there are two integers $(i, j), (j>=i)$ such that $a_j-a_i=D$, where values of $D$ constantly change with different queries.  $n$ ranges from $1$ to $10^5$ and the number of queries of the integer $D$ from $1$ to $10^5$. As you can see, an $O(Qlog(Q))$ solution is necessary. I've tried using a segment tree, even a persistent one, but it doesn't seem to work. Could someone provide a possible solution to this problem?

EDIT: Could someone  explain why the Latex also isn't showing up?

Comment: No latex on this site, best you can do is put your math  between backticks ` `

Comment: sounds like homework.....

Comment: Please respond to the "sounds like homework". This site is not intended for same - and I feel vaguely unclean for answering them.

Comment: Can't you just sort the list, then run two pointers along it in linear time?

Comment: @Eric The (admittedly unreadable) condition that `j>=i` precludes sorting.

Comment: @user3386109 Is that not fixed by sorting the index alongside the array?

Comment: @Eric - that may work for one query, but how will you make it work for more?

Comment: @IVlad: Run the algorithm again? All that (seemed) to be asked for was an n log n solution, which this is. If `a` can be presorted, then it's O(N)

Comment: @Eric, no, it's O(n) **per query**. The limits obviously require better than that.

Comment: @Eric Yes, that's true, that would allow you to perform the first query in O(nlogn) time, since the sort would take O(nlogn) time, and subsequent queries would take O(n) time. Overall, then you would have O(Qn), where Q is the number of queries. That is definitely better than the O(Q n^2) naive algorithm.

Comment: There's an O(n polylog) time algorithm based on FFT.

Comment: This is not homework; I can say that. I reduced an SPOJ problem to this, and I wanted to see whether it's solvable.And can you explain the FFT solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do preprocessing by calculating all the possible n^2 differences possible and maintain a map or hashmap of their modulus, so for every query you just have to find whether the given range exists. Total time would be n^2 + (nlogn or n) + (qlogn or q).